# Infinite Series vs Integral Representation of State Vectors in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

Shankar's *Principles of Quantum Mechanics*, pg. 57-59 subsection *Generalisation to Infinite Dimensions* states that state vectors defined as,

$$|f_n\rangle = \sum_{i} f_n(x_i) |x_i\rangle, \tag{1}$$

exist within a space of dimension $n$ which is 'unspecified but assumed to be some finite number'. The text then goes on to say that for $n\rightarrow\infty$ the series must be replaced with an integral such that the inner product remains finite, i.e.

$$\langle f|f\rangle = \int |f(x)|^2 dx.$$

What I'm trying to understand is when one can let $n\rightarrow\infty$ without assuming one has a continuous basis, i.e. that the $x_i$ remain distinct and the series description (1) is still valid. The inner product,

$$\langle f|f\rangle = \sum_i^\inf |f(x_i)|^2,$$

must be finite which restricts $f$, so does this just define some restricted function space? How does all this link in with the notion of countably infinite and uncountably infinite Hilbert spaces?

Comment: [This answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/359982/50583) might be of use to you.

Comment: Thanks @ACuriousMind this is exactly what I was looking for.