# Is the massless scalar's vacuum in flat space a non-normalizable state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, vacuum

Let us not impose any IR cutoff on Minkowski space. The massive scalar's vacuum is given by a normalizable state. However, since there is a continuum of energies for the massless scalar starting from the vacuum itself, is it correct to conclude that the massless scalar's vacuum is non-normalizable? (Note that the continuum of energy states for massive scalar doesn't start from the vacuum)

There might be another way to see this issue. A free particle in non-relativistic QM doesn't have a normalizable vacuum, however as soon as you turn on a potential we get a normalizable vacuum. Does this logic extend to massless scalar's case as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "non-normalizable state" in a well-defined theory. The theory of the free scalar field lives on the Fock space which is a specific representation of the CCR on the Hilbert space (see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/617834/30833) for the definition). The Hilbert space is by definition normalizable, so all states in the Fock space are normalizable even when $m=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By "well-defined theory", you mean one with an IR cutoff, right? Let's say I don't impose one, then the ground state should be non-normalizable, as in the case of free particle in QM?