Does the Wigner's classification of elementary particles presuppose projective representations?
In many textbooks introducing to QFT, the definition of elementary particles never implies a projective representation. I don't understand why, and that's the subject of my question.
Context
We know that (quantum) physical states $|\psi\rangle$ correspond to rays in a projective Hilbert space$^{[1]}$. Since our physical theory is naturally described by a projective space, it is useful to look at projective representations$^{[2]}$ of the groups of interest (in particular a group like the Poincaré group or any group over maximally symmetric spaces, I suppose).
The following lemma exists:
$$
\text{PGL}(n, V) = \text{GL}(n, V)/V^* \cong \text{SL}(n, V)/C_n
$$
where $C_n$ is the group of $n$th-roots of unity. For example, the projective representation of $\text{SO}^+(1, 3)$ is given by a morphism
$$
\varphi : \text{SO}^+(1, 3) \to \text{SL}(2, \mathbb C) / \{\pm 1\}.
$$
To determine $\varphi$ and projective representations, in general, we can apparently use a theorem, Bargmann's theorem, which states that any projective and unitary representation of a group $G$ can be deduced from unitary and irreducible representations of the universal cover $\text{SL}(n, V)/C_n$ (source: Unitary representations of the Poincare group, by Vincent Bouchard). I don't know this theorem, but apparently it exists.
Question
Is the brief explanation I've given the reason we want to study unitary and irreducible representations of the Poincaré group? Most of the time, explanations motivate this with the arguments involved in a previous question and it never invokes projective representations, which strikes me as rather odd given that projective Hilbert spaces are axiomatic (I think).
So, do the need of studying the Poincaré's irreps follows naturally from the result of Bargmann's theorem? If not, why not? If so, what is the link between "classic motivation" (as asked in the shared question above) and the one presented here?
PS: Bargmann's theorem is mentioned several times in the wikipedia page and on the internet, but I can't seem to find a clear statement. Perhaps it would help me to understand or refuted what my question implies.

[1] The states of a physical system correspond (but not necessarily uniquely) to vectors in a Hilbert space $H$. Physically, the $\psi$ state and the $\lambda\psi$ state (with $\lambda\neq0$) represent the same state and the requirement that $\langle\psi|\psi\rangle = 1$ does not completely determine the $\psi$ state (as it can be multiplied by a $\lambda$ of unit norm). Such a $\lambda$ is written $$ \lambda = e^{i\phi} $$ where $\phi$ is a phase. A projective Hilbert space $P(H)$ of a Hilbert space $H$ corresponds to the set of equivalence classes $[\varphi]$ of non-zero $\varphi\in H$ such that $|\varphi\rangle = \lambda|\psi\rangle$. In our cass, the equivalence class of $\psi$ is the ray $$ R_\psi := \left\{ |\varphi\rangle \in H \;|\; \exists\lambda\in\mathbb C_0 \; |\varphi\rangle = \lambda|\psi\rangle \right\}. $$ In other words, each element of such a ray is statistically indistinguishable (according to Born's rule). A ray is more fundamental than a state $|\psi\rangle$ because it takes into account all physically equivalent states.
[2] A projective representation of any group $G$ on a vector space $V$ with field $K$ is a group homomorphism $G \to \text{PGL}(V)$ where $$ \text{PLG}(V) := \text{GL}(V)/K^* $$ where $K^*$ stands for the normal subgroup of non-zero multiples of the identity.

Why are you talking about Hilbert space? If QFT is in concern here, you should be talking about Fock space with non-fixed number of particles. Mind you that theorems that are applicable to Hilbert space may not necessarily be applicable to Fock space. For example, spontaneous symmetry breaking can only happen in Fock space, while for Hilbert space the vacuum is just a quantum superposition of all the degenerate lowest energy states without symmetry breaking.

@MadMax "Fock space" is a Hilbert space. And the axioms of QM (or QFT if you want to distinguish somehow) do not specify any concrete Hilbert space -- in fact, all (complex, separable/ equal-dimensional) are equivalent anyway, so this does not matter.

@TobiasFünke, you are wrong, see proof here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/617834/is-the-fock-space-defined-in-the-context-of-the-quantum-field-theory-really-a/617932#617932

@MadMax With all due respect, no I am not wrong. With the usual definition or meaning of "Fock space" it should be clear that it is a Hilbert space.

@TobiasFünke, with all due respect, you are wrong. QM Hilbert space is countable in Cantor's sense, while QFT Fock space is NOT countable in Cantor's sense. They are mathematically totally different animals. For instance, any real number can be represented as an infinite string of integers. But real numbers and integer numbers are mathematically totally different entities. Integers are countable, while real numbers are not countable. The same logic applies to Fock space which could be constructed by stacking together infinite number of Hilbert states. Capiche?

@MadMax What's cappish?

@TheIdealis misspelled "capisci"

@MadMax It seems that you are not talking about Hilbert space vs. non-Hilbert space, but rather about separable vs. non-separable (Hilbert spaces). To this end, let me refer once more to e.g. the Wightman Axioms, and also to "Quantum Physics in Non-Separable Hilbert Spaces" by J. Earman; and since you mentioned SSB, see also this PSE thread. --All that being said, I still don't understand your comment(s) regarding this specific question (and its context) here, but that's okay; I did not want to start a discussion.

@MadMax Fock space is a separable Hilbert space. In other words, it is a Hilbert space of countable dimension. It is infact isomorphic (as Hilbert spaces) to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. First of all, it is a countable direct sum of $L^2(X)$s where each $X$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space. It is a standard result that such a Hilbert space is of countable dimension. Then a countable direct sum of Hilbert spaces of countable dimension is of countable dimension. The result follows from the simple fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable.

@MadMax You will essentially never encounter a Hilbert space of uncountable dimension either in physics or in mathematics. Thus, from a practical point of view, there are only two relevant Hilbert spaces up to isomorphism in physics: the finite dimensional Hilbert spaces $\mathbb{C}^N$, and the separable infinite dimensional ones, which are all isomorphic to each-other and to $\ell^2$, the Hilbert space of square-summable sequences. All apparent differences in sizes are superficial or are a consequence of a more complicated algebra of observables.

It depends on what you mean by "the Poincaré group". If you mean
$$
\mathcal P=\mathbb R^d\rtimes SO(d)
$$
(euclidean signature, to simplify notation) then particles are, by definition, projective representations.
If by Poincaré you mean
$$
\hat{\mathcal P}=\mathbb R^d\rtimes Spin(d)
$$
then particles are, by definition, regular representations.
Of course, both definitions are equivalent, since $\hat{\mathcal P}$ is the universal cover of $\mathcal P$.
So, to answer your question: Wigner's classification involves regular representations of Poincaré if by Poincaré you mean $\hat{\mathcal P}$, but it involves projective representations of Poincaré if by Poincaré you mean $\mathcal P$.
