# Discrete and continuous basis in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, notation, discrete

In the context of Quantum Mechanics and Hilbert spaces, I understand that a function can be interpreted as $\psi(x) = \langle x \vert \psi \rangle$ in the position basis, and things like $$\int_a^b|\psi(x)|^2dx$$make sense interpreting $x$ as a label. But if I think of $\psi(x)$ as an element of $L^2$ and expand $\psi(x)$ in a discrete basis, like $\psi(x)=\sum_a(\phi_a(x),\psi(x))\phi_a(x)$, now the label is $a$ and what does $x$ means now and why the inner product is still the same and does not make any reference to $a$?

Comment: Illustrate by Fourier analyzing a periodic function, and then resolving a function in quantum oscillator eigenfunctions. Can you now see the map from natural to real numbers and sharpen your question?

Comment: probably closely related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/359982/50583

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you represent a periodic function by a Fourier series you do pretty much the same thing: you represent it by sines instead of δ-functions.

For your specific example, you have two alternate resolutions of the identity/ completeness relations,
$$
1\!\!1= \int\!\! dx ~|x\rangle\langle x| \\
1\!\!1= \sum_a |a\rangle \langle a|
 $$
where, importantly, $\langle a|x \rangle = \phi_a^* (x)$, your change of basis "matrix".

You then have
$$
\psi(x)=\langle x|\psi\rangle = \sum_a  \langle x|a\rangle \langle a|\psi\rangle =  \sum_a  \phi_a(x) ~~\psi_a, ~~\hbox{where}\\
\psi_a=\langle a|\psi\rangle= \int\!\! dx ~ \phi^*_a(x)~ \psi(x),
$$
by the above completeness relation.
In your expression, you used the same *x* as a variable, and as a dummy integration variable in your inner product--a disastrous practice.

It is ***crucial*** to test-drive this equivalence with the [Hermite functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Natural_length_and_energy_scales) $\psi_n(x)=\langle x|n\rangle$, where the discrete index is the natural number identifying the quantum oscillator energy level, if you have not already done so.

Useful [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64869/hilbert-space-of-harmonic-oscillator-countable-vs-uncountable) as per your comment.

Comment: An important point is also that $\psi(x) \in \mathbb C$ is a number while $|a\rangle, |\psi\rangle \in \mathcal H$ are states on the Hilbert space. However, $|x\rangle$ does (strictly speakin) not exist as a state on the Hilbert space. Only the "bra" $\langle x|$ exists as a linear map on the Hilbert space ($\langle x| : \mathcal H \to \mathbb C$).

This is the reason why they must be treated differently, even though they are similar in prinicple. One would write $|\psi\rangle = \sum_a \psi_a |\phi_a\rangle$ as an equality on $\mathcal H$, but not $|\psi\rangle = \int dx \psi(x) |x\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. This was my first question in this forum. I need to "digest" all these. My goal is to find out how you can do QM without the rigged Hilbert space, delta functional, etc. I know that it has to be with the spectral theorem and that we need to restate our equations in terms of projection operators, which are well-defined in Hilbert space. I need to study. It is not that I don't like the rigged Hilbert space; it is because I want to know why so many books don't talk about it explicitly, but used all the time.

Comment: You say: "In your expression, you used the same x as a variable, and as a dummy integration variable in your inner product--a disastrous practice" ¿How can I write the same expression correctly?

Comment: $\psi(x)=\sum_a(\phi_a(y),\psi(y))~~\phi_a(x)$, but it's still a clumsy expression...

Answer (score 0):

The expression
$$p(a,b)=\int_a^b|\psi(x)|^2dx$$
is the probability that you will find a particle in the interval $[a,b]$. So it is a measurement of position.

The expression
$$\psi(x)=\sum_c(\phi_c(x),\psi(x))\phi_c(x)$$
is writing down a function in terms of other functions, which doesn't change its value anywhere on the interval $[a,b]$ so it won't affect $p(a,b)$. Each $c$ is just a label, like the $x$: it's just a different way of labeling the same function.

Comment: You're right. Thanks.